# Custom view pager with Gradient Background

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, gradient, android-tabs

How can we create a custom gradient background view pager like timely app.
I am able to create radial gradient like below 
in my tab fragment xml

```
<view
android:id="@+id/myView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
class="com.android.MyView" />
```

MyView.java

```
   public class MyView extends View {

Paint BackPaint = new Paint();
Context MyContext;

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context ctx) {
    MyContext = ctx;
    BackPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    BackPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int h = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    float w, h, cx, cy, radius;
    w = getWidth();
    h = getHeight();
    cx = w / 2;
    cy = h / 2;

    if (w > h) {
        radius = h / 4;
    } else {
        radius = w / 4;
    }

    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, w, h, BackPaint);

    Paint MyPaint = new Paint();
    MyPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

    float shaderCx = 0;
    float shaderCy = 0;

    float shaderRadius = w;

    int shaderColor0 = Color.WHITE;
    int shaderColor1 = Color.BLACK;
    shaderColor0 = prefs.getInt("pref1", 0);
    shaderColor1 = prefs.getInt("pref2", 0);
    MyPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    Shader radialGradientShader;

    radialGradientShader = new RadialGradient(shaderCx, shaderCy,
            shaderRadius, shaderColor0, shaderColor1,
            Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);

    MyPaint.setShader(radialGradientShader);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, w, h, MyPaint);
    // canvas.drawRect(0, 0, w, h, MyPaint);

    // canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, MyPaint);
};
```

}

but how can we create separate gradient for each tab?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I believe that if you set the background of each view with a custom drawable that has a startColor and endColor, it will do what you need. You do not need to override the onDraw and do it by hand.

Comment: I want end user to create gradient of his own by using color picker.
I saved those colors using shared preferences and then i am trying to  create Radial Gradient like this.
Can you please check timely app in below link http://www.bitspin.ch/

Comment: I saw timely app, radial background is for fragment inside viewpager